# Transferir arquivos em rede C#

Tags: c#, .net, socket, redes

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de transferir arquivos em uma rede local sem a utilização da Classe Socket em C#? e em termos de performance qual o método mais rápido de transferência de arquivos em uma rede local?

Comment: Por que não transfere direto pelo *file system* usando **`File.Copy()`**?

Comment: Poderia me mandar um exemplo de uma implementação.

Comment: **`File.Copy(@"C:\Pasta\Arquivo.txt", @"\\192.168.25.10\Pasta-Compartilhada\Arquivo.txt");`** - Obviamente só vai funcionar se tiver uma pasta compartilhada e o usuário ter acesso à pasta.

Comment: @jbueno Provavelmente seu comentário se resume na resposta. O Victor não se manisfestou mais.

Comment: Foi uma boa resposta e sinalizei o comentário como muito útil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar [**`File.Copy`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
File.Copy(@"C:\Pasta\Arquivo.txt", @"\\192.168.25.10\Pasta-Compartilhada\Arquivo.txt");
```

Obviamente só vai funcionar se tiver uma pasta compartilhada e o usuário ter acesso à pasta.